Neural network with just one Dense layer
I have a model which works well with just one Dense layer. My model has an input layer, a Dense layer, and then one Reshape layer, which reshapes the output into the desired form. Normally, neural network models consist of one or more hidden layers and then one output layer. My model's performance certainly improves if I add another Dense layer, and then I can say that my model has one hidden layer and one output layer.
But in the case where it has only one Dense layer, should that layer be considered a hidden layer or an output layer?

With just one Dense layer, you have an output layer. The hidden layers would be the layers between the output layer and the input layer.

Thanks for the answer. If the Dense layer I have is actually the output layer, then what could be the reason that the model is performing well? I tried using more layers as well and the model works well in both cases

No problem! It depends on your problem's dataset: as you add more layers, your network becomes capable of learning more complex patterns. Maybe your only layer has complexity enough to perform well on your data.
